# How to download a file from Sharepoint Online using an access token

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, sharepoint-online, adal

I know this has been asked quite a few times already, but I have not been able to find a working solution to my problem yet.

**Problem:**

I need to download a file from a Sharepoint Online site using a C# app using CSOM and a JWT token. When I come to the point where I call this method

```
File.OpenBinaryDirect(ClientContext context, string serverRelativeUrl);
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I authenticate my application in Azure AD using a certificate. It works fine for accessing SharePoint lists, list items and so on, which means that downloading files is the only part where I get this error message.

**What I've done**

I've done some research on the matter and found one thread on MSDN from 2 years ago (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7746d857-d351-49cc-b2f0-496663239e02/how-to-download-a-file-version-from-office-365-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment) mentioning that it was impossible to download files from SP using access tokens.

This is an old thread, so something must have changed since then, but so far I have not been able to find a working solution.

All the articles I come across on the Internet mention providing user credentials to the context. But my client insists on using certificates. Because of that I cannot use this approach

**Question**

Is there a way I can download files from Sharepoint Online using a JWT token?

Answer (score 3):

While looking for a solution, I stumbled upon an MSDN article describing the Sharepoint Online REST API and there was a File endpoint and I decided to give it a try.
Here is what I've come up with:

```
public byte[] GetFileContent(File file)
{
    var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        .Create($"{_serviceDefinition.ServiceId}/_api/Web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{file.ServerRelativeUrl}')/$value");

    request.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {GetAccessToken()}");

    byte[] fileData = new byte[0];

    using (var sr = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            }

            fileData = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

Long story short I create an HttpWebRequest to the following URL: https://{address.of.your.sharepoint.site}/_api/Web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{file.ServerRelativeUrl}')/$value, add my bearer token to the request and then read the response into a byte array for further processing.

Works like a charm but breaks the concept of the CSOM a bit.

Comment: Yep that's the ticket. If you are in CSOM you just need to switch over to the HTTP client version of the downloads and make sure it has a Bearer Token